# An idiomatic word meaning "very good" in this context

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

The country's ranking in global output has been _____ for quite some time now.

What is an idiomatic adjective, or adjectival phrase, meaning "very positive" or "very good" or "very high", to put in the above sentence. Or are each of these three options idiomatic when we talk of ranking?

Thesaurus give a lot of options, among which "outstanding" sounds not a bad option to me, but I still don't know which one is idiomatic when we are talking about rankings.

I am not looking for words that add other meanings. For example, "promising" seems to me to add a sense about future and consequences, and that is why it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: A lot of expressions can serve the purpose. This is a POB issue.

Comment: The description "outstanding" seems to imply the top ranking. My suggestion is **impressive**.

Answer (score 1):

**phenomenal** serves the purpose.

Here are three links which show synonyms for **phenomenal**.You can use any of them for your  sentence.

https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/wondrous

https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/remarkable

https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/phenomenal

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "on the rise" if you prefer an idiom.
There are virtually an indefinite number of expressions that can satisfy the requirement-astonishing, phenomenal, spectacular, impressive, remarkable and so on and so forth.